# Зависание при запуске демона Namenode

Tags: java, linux, unix, map-reduce

Я изменил порт с 9000 на 5000 в конфигурационном файле `core-site.xml` и запустил скрипт

```
./hadoop namenode
```

и в результате получил следующие сообщения (привожу только часть, что увидел с экрана, так как в лог-файл не записалось)

```
13/02/17 22:42:39 INFO http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
13/02/17 22:42:40 INFO http.HttpServer: dfs.webhdfs.enabled=false
13/02/17 22:42:40 INFO http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50070
13/02/17 22:42:40 INFO http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 50070 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 50070
13/02/17 22:42:40 INFO http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50070
13/02/17 22:42:40 INFO mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50070

13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO namenode.Namenode: Web-server up at: 0.0.0.0:50070
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 9 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 8 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 7 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 6 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 5 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 4 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 3 on 5000: starting
13/02/17 22:42:52 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 5000: starting
```

На этом процесс остановился и уже висит несколько часов. Такое уже было в прошлый раз и снял его нажатием `Ctrl+Z`, но в результате при следующем запуске демона `Namenode` с помощью

```
./hadoop namenode
```

я получал сообщения, приведенные в [Ошибка запуска демона Namenode](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/194042/). Что мне делать: останавливать процесс (но тогда необходима перезагрузка виртуальной машины и возможно изменение порта, а в перспективе непонятно - не зависнет ли в следующий раз) или же ждать? Но в любом случае пока что ситуация безвыходная (относительно запуска `Namenode`), поэтому надеюсь, что будут предложены альтернативные варианты.

Comment: Данный лог не очень полезен, т.к. он отражает процесс запуска. См. сообщения уровня WARN и ERROR.

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите убить процесс, жмите <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> меняет состояние процесса на suspend, соответственно он продолжает занимать ваш 5000-й порт.

Вернуть процесс из suspend-а можно командой `fg`